# Understanding the low upload rate of my NAS

Tags: internet

My Internet provider box can be used as a NAS. I put movies on it intending to watch them ideally in streaming or to download them from outside of my box network on my phone/computer device. However the downloading is really really slow. I guess it's because of the upload rate of my NAS.

So, is the upload rate of my NAS equal to the upload rate of my Internet line ? (which is equal to 1Mb/s). I have an ADSL line, would a fibre or VDSL line solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to stream movies that are stored on-premise (in your home) to off-premise (somewhere remotely) then yes, your total available streaming bandwidth will be equivalent to the upstream bandwidth of your service provider. Any other use of the internet will reduce this bandwidth additionally.

It sounds like you've already experienced that 1MB/s is really quite low for video streaming. It's not terrible for regular internet browsing and usage, but anytime you try to upload anything to the internet (like you saved movies) it's going to be really slooooooowwww.

Unfortunately, this is a typical speed for ADSL service and you might have to explore a different type of service all together to get any better performance. So, a fiber, VDSL or coaxial cable service would be much better.